# Open via href a specific broswer

Tags: email, uri, href

I have in an email a href and need to always open that link with google chrome independant of what the default browser is.
"href=googlechrome://http://my.webite.com" is not working. Any suggestions ?
Best Michael

Comment: Can you try "href=googlechrome:http://my.webite.com"

Comment: Hi, same result. protocol not understood or associated with any program. While I have Chrome installed on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for an email to control which piece of software handles URLs in it.

Comment: Hi - At least I was able to get it working for microsoft-edge like href=microsoft-edge:my.webite.com